# is there an alternative to DOMAttrModified that will work in webkit

Tags: dom, webkit, mutation-events

I need to leverage this DOM event. IE has onpropertychange, which does what I need it to do also. Webkit doesn't seem to support this event, however. Is there an alternative I could use?

Comment: I was able to come up with something based on this [http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/453942.aspx](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/453942.aspx)

Comment: Based on the [solution by David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion) I have created a small library to catch DOM insertions. If you can write a CSS selector that matches to the element after the change you are interested in - this is a valid solution. It covers more browsers than DOM Mutation Observers. See: https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Although Chrome does not dispatch `DOMAttrModified` events, the more lightweighted mutation observers are supported since 2011 and these work for attribute changes, too.

Here is an example for the document body:

```
var element = document.body, bubbles = false;

var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(attrModified);
});
observer.observe(element, { attributes: true, subtree: bubbles });

function attrModified(mutation) {
  var name = mutation.attributeName,
    newValue = mutation.target.getAttribute(name),
    oldValue = mutation.oldValue;

  console.log(name, newValue, oldValue);
}
```

For a simple attribute change, the `console.log` statement would print:

```
<body color="black">
<script type="text/html">
document.body.setAttribute("color", "red");
</script>
</body>
```

Console:

`> color red black`

Comment: It seems that this will currently not work in combination with the CSS3 "resize: both" property. The observer will not pick up changes to the element by the user dragging the resize handle.

Comment: Is there any way I can see where the change originated from? I've got an element whose class is being changed somewhere through JS, and I'm trying to figure out where from, but Chrome's stack trace of the event doesn't show the code that initiated the event.

Comment: it's worth noting that `DOMAttrModified` triggers immediately when the attribute changes, but mutation observers queue an event.  So there's a not-so-subtle difference between the two.

Comment: I believe the `Webkit` prefix is no longer necessary. https://caniuse.com/#search=MutationObserver

Answer (score 14):

If you are happy with merely detecting calls to `setAttribute()` (as opposed to monitoring all attribute modifications) then you could over-ride that method on all elements with:

```
Element.prototype._setAttribute = Element.prototype.setAttribute
Element.prototype.setAttribute = function(name, val) { 
 var e = document.createEvent("MutationEvents"); 
 var prev = this.getAttribute(name); 
 this._setAttribute(name, val);
 e.initMutationEvent("DOMAttrModified", true, true, null, prev, val, name, 2);
 this.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and was thinking of modifying `setAttribute`, so seeing [what Sean did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2370755/3991783), I copied that.  Worked great, except that it was firing when an attribute was repeatedly set to the same value, so I added a check to my copy to skip firing the event if the value is not being changed.  I also added `val = String(val)`, based on the rationale that  `setAttribute` will coerce numbers to strings, so the comparison should anticipate that.

My modified version is:

```
var emulateDOMAttrModified = {

  isSupportedNatively: function () {
    var supported = false;
    function handler() {
      supported = true;
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', handler);
    var attr = 'emulateDOMAttrModifiedTEST';
    document.body.setAttribute(attr, 'foo'); // aka $('body').attr(attr, 'foo');
    document.removeEventListener('DOMAttrModified', handler);
    document.body.removeAttribute(attr);
    return supported;
  },

  install: function () {
    if (!this.isSupportedNatively() &&
      !Element.prototype._setAttribute_before_emulateDOMAttrModified) {
      Element.prototype._setAttribute_before_emulateDOMAttrModified = Element.prototype.setAttribute
      Element.prototype.setAttribute = function(name, val) {
        var prev = this.getAttribute(name);
        val = String(val); /* since attributes do type coercion to strings,
           do type coercion here too; in particular, D3 animations set x and y to a number. */
        if (prev !== val) {
          this._setAttribute_before_emulateDOMAttrModified(name, val);
          var e = document.createEvent('MutationEvents');
          e.initMutationEvent('DOMAttrModified', true, true, null, prev, val, name, 2);
          this.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
      };
    }
  }

};

// Install this when loaded.  No other file needs to reference this; it will just make Chrome and Safari
// support the standard same as Firefox does.
emulateDOMAttrModified.install();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer code:
https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange/blob/master/attrchange.js
'DOMAttrModified' + ('propertychange' for IE) are used there like in your case. If it's not suitable for you, the "ugly" solution that can satisfy this demand should be setInterval(function(){}, delay)
Otherwise see Sean Hogan post above.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Filip is close (and may have worked at the time) but now you need to request delivery of the old attribute value.

Thus, you'll want to change :

```
observer.observe(element, { attributes: true, subtree: bubbles });
```

to this:

```
observer.observe(element, { attributes: true, attributeOldvalue:true, subtree: bubbles });
```

Otherwise, you won't see the oldValues (you'll get null instead.) This was tested in Chrome 34.0.1847.131 (Official Build 265687) m.