# How can I detect with JavaScript when an element's styles change in Webkit? (Since DomAttrModified doesn't appear to be supported)

Tags: javascript, webkit, mutation-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there an alternative to DOMAttrModified that will work in webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882224/is-there-an-alternative-to-domattrmodified-that-will-work-in-webkit)

I'm trying to detect with JavaScript when an element's styles have been changed. If this change is detected (.NET validators becoming visible when triggered), it triggers another change elsewhere on the page (a visual effect on an unrelated element not controlled by the .NET code.)

Using DomAttrModified (or propertychange for IE) I'm able to set an event handler that notifies me when the change takes place. But this isn't supported by Webkit. Is there an alternative or slightly different handler that would do what I'm seeking?

Here's a demo page showing what I currently have working for Firefox and IE: http://cssquirrel.com/testcases/detect-style-change/

Thoughts?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882224/is-there-an-alternative-to-domattrmodified-that-will-work-in-webkit

Answer (score 0):

Use `.watch()` jQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/watch