# Jquery and Bootstrap Columns

Tags: jquery, css, grid

I am pretty new to bootstrap but I was trying to implement the grid system. I wanted to know if it was possible to check what size column is currently running and then adjust your css based off of it. So if it was col-lg-12 it would do nothing but if it became col-md-12 then it would change .class {display: block;} to .class{display: inline;}

Comment: how about using media queries for your breakpoints and then override the display type for the specific class.

Answer (score 0):

[JS to monitor the CSS property change like "display:none"=>"display:block"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458428/js-to-monitor-the-css-property-change-like-displaynone-displayblock)

Maybe try using the following to catch changes to property and adjust the display property in the handler?