# How to detect the position of an element changed?

Tags: javascript

Consider the situation where **div-A** has a relative position to **div-B** (actually,**div-A** is hovering over **div-B** by different **Z-Index**). When the position of **div-B** changes, **div-C** is to be inserted before it and **div-A** is to be hidden.

The question is: how to detect the position changing of **div-B**?

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on can cause the divs to move, if it's a window resizing `window.onresize = function(){}` or in jQuery `$(window).resize(function(){});`
 if it's caused by user interaction (like clicks and what have you): `document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){},false);`, where the handler is preferably a closure of sorts, that holds the initial position of the divs in question.
If it's caused by new content inserted due to an ajax call: let the `onreadystatechange` handler sort it out. Again, preferably use a closure to compare the position to the initial values

There might be an easier CSS3 way, I'm no designer - so I don't really know. Also: set up a fiddle of what you've tried so far an what your page looks like. And be a bit more precise about this issue. Your question is terribly vague. Read the [FAQ's](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: I prefer a universal solution,here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882224/is-there-an-alternative-to-domattrmodified-that-will-work-in-webkit has a hint

Comment: That so if you have an answer, why ask the question? If this doesn't answer your question, again, please specify when this event should fire

Answer (score -2):

You can use the $.position method in jquery:

```
  $('#element_id').position().left;
  $('#element_id').position().top;
```

Just store those in a variable and then actively monitor if it changes using the `setInterval()` method

Comment: Terribly brutal approach. Assuming jQ when there's nothing to suggest jQ is on the table. Telling somebody how to get the possition, but not how to use it isn't an answer. Sorry but -1