# JQuery binding events with propertychange and DomAttrModified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an application and i have use a property where a small change in *textarea* should alert the user, i tried **onChange** events, but that does not server the Purpose, i found **onPropertyChange** seems to be working fine in IE only, i had to make this application cross browser was looking something like an attribute of **onpropertychange** with other browsers. Looked at **DomAttrModified**, but that seems not working any idea, how can i do: Here is my below code:

```
$("#info").bind('keyup keydown keypress onDOMAttrModified propertychange', function(evt)
    { var keyCode = evt.which; 
        var text_area =$(this).val(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Don't prepend "on". Just use `DOMAttrModified`

Comment: Although I'm confused why `onchange` doesn't work for you. Maybe you're looking for `oninput`?

Answer (score 3):

try

replace `onDOMAttrModified` with `DOMAttrModified`

```
$("#info").bind('keyup keydown keypress DOMAttrModified propertychange',
```

Comment: Hi, I just added few more and changed this as `keyup keydown keypress hover change focusin focus focusout DOMAttrModified`, but except IE, it is not working on anybrowser,

Comment: @gurpreet-randhawa, maybe it does not work in some of your browser because of the following issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1882224/923560